# Unable to view Japanese characters in Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, sublimetext2, notepad++

My text editors (eclipse, sublime 2, notepad++)  can't show Japanese letter. But I can read Japanese letter in web browser, file title and MS word.

I was working on a Japanese project. I can view Japanese letter for the first month, but now I don't know why all my editors went wrong without reason.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question to me. (You should make sure you're using a suitable file encoding, such as UTF-8, and inform your editor of the encoding you *are* using, but that's not really a matter for SO.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [looking for a UTF-8 text editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217089/looking-for-a-utf-8-text-editor)

Comment: I copied and installed all Japanese font from my project-team, but it still can't read Japanese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Windows 7 OS. Then go to the Control Panel, open the Region and Language Settings. On the Administrative tab, click "Change system locale...", change it to `Japanese (Japan)`. Japanese characters should be displayed now.

Another possible option to just read those Japanese characters might be to try EditPad Pro which has more encoding including Japanese etc.

Comment: That will change entire OS to Japanese, OP did not ask for that. OP wants view only few files in Japanese, not entire OS.

Comment: Based on what s/he said, the Japanese characters s/he wants to display aren't Unicode encoded probably, but just normal Japanese encoding, so cannot correct it in most editors by choosing Unicode options. Another possible option might be to try EditPad Pro which can choose more encoding including Japanese etc.

Comment: _"Unicode encoded probably"_ Unicode is **not** an encoding, it's a character set. You need to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13212528/2982225) for better understanding. You may want to improve your answer, as technical inaccuracies tend to attract downvotes - that's just my humble suggestion.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that. i should say Unicode related encoding in my comment, but unable to change the comment now after 5 mins.